# how to achieve the alpha matting algorithm using python

Tags: python, alpha

I want to extract the foreground in image. I know that the grabcut can achieve it. But I want to use the alpha matting method. I'm searching the code that alpha matting algorithm by python and I can't find it. Can you help me? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of a tool you can use out of the box that does what you want, but here is a method you can use to implement alpha matting:

1. I'd explore [Pillow](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow) (Python Image Library fork).
2. Specifically, I'd look into the `.split()` method [found here](https://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/Image.html?highlight=split#PIL.Image.Image.split), which splits the image into R, G,B, and A bands.
3. From there you should be able to `.filter()` on the appropriate band to [find edges](https://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/ImageFilter.html) and outline them.
4. After [recomposing](https://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/Image.html?highlight=composite#PIL.Image.composite)/[merging](https://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/Image.html?highlight=composite#PIL.Image.merge) and [saving](https://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/Image.html?highlight=save#PIL.Image.Image.save) the image, the result should be alpha matted.